# How to? Insert current date from Android into mySQL database using Retrofit2

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, retrofit2

Trying to insert Current date from android to mysql via Retrofit. The date is showing in the mysql database as 0000-00-00. I've read over multiple threads on SO on this topic and tried to apply the answers but so far I have not been successful. Please see the below code snippets for context.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$moodBefore = $_POST['moodBefore'];
$automaticThought = $_POST['automaticThought'];
$distortions = $_POST['distortions'];
$challengeThought = $_POST['challengeThought'];
$alternativeThought = $_POST['alternativeThought'];
$moodAfter = $_POST['moodAfter'];
$posted = $_POST['posted'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO Cbt ( userId, moodBefore,   automaticThought, distortions, challengeThought, alternativeThought, moodAfter, posted) VALUES
('$userId','$moodBefore', '$automaticThought', '$distortions', '$challengeThought', '$alternativeThought', '$moodAfter', '$posted')";

  $resultinsert = $conn -> query($insert);
              if(!$resultinsert){
                  echo $conn->error;
        }
 ?>
```

RETROFIT API CODE:

```
public interface Api {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("insert.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> insertLog(
            @Field("userId") int userId,
            @Field("moodBefore") int moodBefore,
            @Field("automaticThought") String automaticThought,
            @Field("distortions") int distortions,
            @Field("challengeThought") String challengeThought,
            @Field("alternativeThought") String alternativeThought,
            @Field("moodAfter") int moodAfter,
            @Field("posted") String date
    );
```

JAVA CODE:

```
String posted = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(new Date());

case R.id.nextBtnMoodPage:
                if (hasSelected) {

                    Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
                            .getInstance()
                            .getApi()
                            .insertLog(userId, moodBefore, automaticThoughtString, distortions, challengeThoughtString, alternativeThoughtString, moodAfter, posted);

                    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {.....and so on
```

I would like the date to insert succesfully and not show 0000-00-00
If I could also make the date show as DD-MM-YYYY that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the Java code, all other parts of the code stay the same

```
private Date currentDate() {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String posted = dateFormat.format(currentDate());
```